# Export PowerPoint presentation as PDF when hitting save with VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation saved as `.pptm`. I want the presentation to be automatically exported to PDF whenever I save it (that is, whenever I press `CTRL+S`).

In the Visual Basic view, I have created a new module under `VBAProject`:

```
VBAProject
|-- Modules
    |-- Module1
```

In `Module1`, I have added the following code:

```
Private Sub App_PresentationBeforeSave(ByVal Pres As Presentation, ByVal Cancel As Boolean)
    ' PDF Filename
    Dim PDF_Filename As String
    PDF_Filename = "C:/Users/user/directory/file.pdf"
    'Export the presentation as PDF when saving
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat PDF_Filename, ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint ppFixedFormatTypePDF
End Sub
```

This is not working, as when I update the presentation (`CTRL+S`), no PDF file is produced.

From experience working with VBA for Excel and Word, I have the suspicion that the code should be placed in `ThisWorkbook`, however, there is no such construct or similarly named item in the VBA view, `VBAProject` was empty when I accessed it.

How can I make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code relies on responding to an application event, but in order to make it fire, you must set up an event trap. Jamie Garroch has the best and most complete explanation of this I've seen here:

http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/

Comment: It works when adding the `Main` Module as explained in the guide you included and wrapping my code within the `clsAppEvents` class module that the guide mentions.
However, the only issue I have with it is that I have to manually Run `InitApp` when opening the presentation before the actual macro gets executed when saving the slideshow.
Isn't there a way of it running upon opening the slideshow, so that whenever I hit `CTRL+S`, the code is run? At least with Excel and Word I don't have to run anything manually for a macro to get executed...

Comment: I have found [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391808/how-to-write-auto-macros-in-powerpoint-2013), where Jon Peltier's answer explains how to add XML to the .pptm file so that it runs VBA code automatically. With this, my code works and it runs automatically.

Comment: Good find ... thanks for coming back with that.